# Sync deleted event instances in Office365 API

Tags: java, rest, outlook, office365, office365api

I'm following the documentation about synchronizing the events:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/sync-calendar-view

Using this service I can get all the events and their occurrences(for repeatable ones). The problem comes when some of the occurrences become removed. This service just doesn't return them and I can't identify in my application whether some occurrence was deleted or not. Is there a way to detect whether some occurrence was deleted or not and to get information about at least id or data/time of this occurrence?